# Как каждую секунду вызывать метод?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В WPF/MVVM игре есть модель часов, которые изменяются каждую секунду.
А в другой модели описаны свойства игрока - голод и усталость.

Я хочу изменять эти параметры каждую секунду. Как модель игрока может узнать, что в другой модели есть часы?
И это вообще нормально - чтобы модели взаимодействовали друг с другом?

**Часы:**

```
class TimerData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimerData()
    {
        TimeFormat = "Время 09:00 AM";
        Hours = 9;
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private DispatcherTimer Timer;

    private string _timeFormat;
    public string TimeFormat
    {
        get { return _timeFormat; }
        set
        {
            _timeFormat = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _minutes;
    public int Minutes
    {
        get { return _minutes; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 61)
            {
                _minutes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _hours;
    public int Hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 25)
            {
                _hours = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Minutes++;
        if (Minutes > 59)
        {
            Minutes = 0;
            Hours++;

            if (Hours > 23)
                Hours = 0;
        }

        UpdateTimeFormat();
    }

    private void UpdateTimeFormat()
    {
        TimeFormat = string.Format("Время {0:00}:{1:00} AM", Hours, Minutes);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

**Игрок**

```
public class Parameters : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Parameters()
    {
        Satiety = 30;
        Fatigue = 70;
    }

    private int _satiety;
    public int Satiety
    {
        get { return _satiety; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 101)
            {
                _satiety = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        } 
    }

    private int _fatigue;
    public int Fatigue
    {
        get { return _fatigue; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 101)
            {
                _fatigue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    // Как каждую секунду вызывать этот метод?
    private void DecreaseSatiety()
    {

    }

    // Как каждую секунду вызывать этот метод?
    private void DecreaseFatigue()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: А что плохого в том, что вы будете использовать модель в модели? Сделайте в вашей `TimerData` событие, которое будет оповещать о "тике" и подпишитесь на него внутри `Parameters`, вот и вся реализация. Только работайте с уже ранее созданной моделью, ибо как я понял ваш таймер - один на все приложение, а значит нового создавать вам нельзя, только передача ссылки и работа с ней!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо. А почему новый таймер нельзя создавать? Это ресурсоемко?

Comment: Почему нельзя, можно. Только вы что хотите в итоге получить, что бы у вас было 1000 таймеров и по тику определенного было определенное действие, или все же один таймер, который инициализирует всю остальную логику? Тут решайте сами.

Comment: Обычно в играх один игровой цикл, скажем Quake. И даже с ним бывают проблемы (сетевой режим игры, когда приходится кучу клиентов синхронизировать с сервером). Так что я однозначно за один таймер.